# Instagram Filter Image Manipulation asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

I've found [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-instagram-filters-with-php/). However it is for php, does an equivalent library exist for asp.net?

Is there anything similar to this for ASP.net that mimics the kind of filters you'll find on instagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently found [AForge.net](http://www.aforgenet.com/) which amongst many things will do image processing and has a select amount of basic filters I believe will be able to achieve what I need it for. The docs on there site are also really good.

To apply a Sepia filter to an image:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pathToImage);

Sepia filter = new Sepia();

filter.ApplyInPlace(bmp);
```